# Изменения значения select

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма, в ней сотрудник вводит данные, в конце нажимает на кнопку и создается .htm файл.

Данные сотрудник может вводить на 2 языках, язык выбирает сам.

```
<label for="lang">Выберите язык:</label><br>
<select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option value="Ru">Русский</option>         
    <option value="Eng">Английский</option>                         
</select>
```

По окончанию ввода данных, все введенное передается на другую форму

```
<form id="VeryAction" action="action.php" method="post">
```

И все вроде бы работает, но есть нюанс. В форме есть select с городами

```
<label for="town">Город:</label><br>
<select name="town" id="town">
    <option value="1">Мурманск</option>
    <option value="2">Москва</option>
    <option value="3">Санкт-Петербург</option>
    <option value="4">Сочи</option>
</select>
```

Если русский язык, города по русски, если английский то по английски. Так же в зависимости от языка изменятся ссылка в action.

```
<div class="allbutton">
<button id="CreatePod" class="CreatePod" type="submit">Создать</button>
```

```
     <script>
         var select, value, langv, langs;

         document.getElementById('CreatePod').onclick = function() {
             select = document.getElementById("town");
             value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

             langs = document.getElementById("lang");
             langv = langs.options[langs.selectedIndex].value;

             alert(langv);

             if ( langv === 'Eng') {
                 if (value === "1") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ""}
                 if (value === "2") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ",  Moscow"}
                 if (value === "3") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ",  St. Petersburg"}
                 if (value === "4") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ",  Sochi"}
                 $('#VeryAction').attr('action', 'actionEng.php');
             }

             if ( langv === 'Ru') {
                 if (value === "1") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ""}
                 if (value === "2") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ",  Москва"}
                 if (value === "3") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ",  Санкт-Петербург"}
                 if (value === "4") {select.options[select.selectedIndex].value = ",  Сочи"}
                 $('#VeryAction').attr('action', 'action.php');
             }
         }
     </script>
```

Проблема возникает в случае, если сотрудник вбил данные, на каком то языке, нажал кнопку, а потом просто переключил язык и снова нажал кнопку, при этом город не изменит язык.
При этом, если ввести данные - нажать на кнопку создания - изменить язык и изменить город все отработает как нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эмм... можно использовать массивы, и не заморачиваясь, сразу переключать всё:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/k54wL9su/)

```js
(function(){

var rutown = ['Мурманск', 'Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Сочи'];
var entown = ['Murmansk', 'Moscow', 'St. Peterburg', 'Sochi'];
var list = document.getElementById('town').getElementsByTagName('option');

document.getElementById('lang').addEventListener('input', function(){
  var x = rutown;
  if( this.value == 'Ru' ) { 
    x = rutown; 
    //$('#VeryAction').attr('action', 'actionEng.php');
  } else if( this.value == 'Eng' ) {
    x = entown;
    //$('#VeryAction').attr('action', 'action.php');
  }
  /* каждому элементу массива соответствует свой элемент option */
  var i;
  for( i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ){
      list[i].innerText = x[i];
  }
});

})();
```

```html
<label for="lang">Выберите язык:</label><br>
<select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option value="Ru">Русский</option>         
    <option value="Eng">English</option>                         
</select> 

<br><br>

<label for="town">Город:</label><br>
<select name="town" id="town">
    <option value="1">Мурманск</option>
    <option value="2">Москва</option>
    <option value="3">Санкт-Петербург</option>
    <option value="4">Сочи</option>
</select>
```

P.s. [Switch - Case](http://learn.javascript.ru/switch)

Comment: Спасибо, тоже начинал склонятся к этому варианту

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать шаблон и из него при смене языка выбирать данные по принципу `ключ => значение` и менять подписи у полей ввода, а также атрибут `action` формы.

```js
// Задаем локали по принципу `i18n`.
const LOCALES = {
  "Eng": {
    "action": "actionEng.php",
    "town": {
      "1": "Murmansk",
      "2": "Moscow",
      "3": "St. Petersburg",
      "4": "Sochi"
    }
  },
  "Ru": {
    "action": "action.php",
    "town": {
      "1": "Мурманск",
      "2": "Москва",
      "3": "Санкт-Петербург",
      "4": "Сочи"
    }
  }
}

// Выбираем элементы с которыми будем работать.
const MAINFORM = document.getElementById('feedback_form');
const LANG_BOX = MAINFORM.elements.lang;
const TOWN_BOX = MAINFORM.elements.town;

// Добавлем функцию-обработчик, которая будет выполняться
// при выборе языка в выпадающем списке.
LANG_BOX.addEventListener('input', changeLocale);

// Функция изменения атрибута `action` у формы и
// языка городов в выпадающем списке.
function changeLocale(event) {
  // Текущий выбранный язык.
  const lang = LANG_BOX.value;

  // Меняем action формы.
  MAINFORM.action = LOCALES[lang].action;

  // Перебираем все `option` выпадающего списка города.
  [...TOWN_BOX.options].forEach(function(option) {
    // Ставим соответствующий для города текст.
    option.text = LOCALES[lang].town[option.value];
  });
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form id="feedback_form" action="action.php" method="post">
  <label for="lang">Выберите язык:</label>
  <select id="lang" name="lang">
    <option value="Ru" selected>Русский</option>
    <option value="Eng">Английский</option>
  </select>

  <label for="town">Город:</label>
  <select id="town" name="town">
    <option value="1" selected>Мурманск</option>
    <option value="2">Москва</option>
    <option value="3">Санкт-Петербург</option>
    <option value="4">Сочи</option>
  </select>

  <hr>
  <button type="submit">Создать</button>
</form>
```